# Sculpting not updating in Lookdev and Rendered mode (2.8)

Tags: sculpting

While sculpting, the model doesn't update in Lookdev and Rendered mode (EEVEE). It's as nothing is happening while I sculpt, but when I change to object mode, all the sculpting shows up. 
I can have real time sculpting in Lookdev/Renderer if I'm using Dyntopo. That's the only way. But sometimes I don't want Dyntopo...

All help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an actual question or is this a bug report?

Comment: Question. I suppose I'm doing something wrong probably...